# log4j v1.x how to add property to log4j.xml like for log4j.properties

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, logging, log4j

I have a little problem with configuring log4j to show hibernate queries with binded values.

I need to add `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace` to `log4j.properties`, but a have log4j.xml.

The question is **how can I configure this property for log4j.xml?** Found many examples how to configure appenders and so on within xml but no one 'how to configure additional properties with xml'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.type">
    <level value="TRACE"/>
</logger>
```

Just in case you have similar problems in future [this](http://log4j-props2xml.appspot.com/) might be useful. From my experience it is quite accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in your configuration (.xml) file should solve it: `<Logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="trace" />`